# Rails: Return limited number of records as well as first

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 Rails models, `Client` and `CheckIn`:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :check_ins
end

class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

Normally when I fetch all `:check_ins` for a `:client` I call:

```
Client.find(1).check_ins
```

I've noticed that as the number of `:check_ins` increases, I am wasting memory and so I'd like to **return the 10 most recent records, as well as the single oldest record**.  I would also like the returned items to be an `#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` and not an array.

How might I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

Combining oldest and newest records in a single SQL query is possible with UNION. So you could write it as:

```
query = "(SELECT * FROM #{CheckIn.table_name} WHERE client = :client_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10) UNION (SELECT * FROM #{CheckIn.table_name} WHERE client = :client_id ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1)"
CheckIn.find_by_sql [query, { client_id: client_id }]
```

However result will be an `Array`, not `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`

Comment: I specifically asked for an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`.  I guess its not possible in Rails 4

Answer (score -1):

I think that [scoping](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) is what you're looking for

```
  class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    scope :recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) }
    scope :oldest, -> { order(created_at: :asc).limit(10) }
  end

  > Client.find(1).check_ins.recent
  => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [ ...]>
  > Client.find(1).check_ins.oldest
```

Comment: this does not include their **oldest** as well

Comment: Just use the same logic to create another scope @JeremyThomas

Comment: I understand that maybe my wording wasn't clear but I was asking for the **single oldest record** and the **10 most recent records**.